# Raspberry Pi crashes when I try to build the Catkin workspace

Tags: ros, catkin, build, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I am trying to follow [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi#Setup_ROS_Repositories) guide here to start using the Robot Operating System (currently ROS Indigo). I am at the very final stage where I am trying to build the Catkin workspace using the command:

> sudo
> ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated
> --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo This command is from Section 3.3

It works perfectly fine for the first 50 packages or so, but starts hanging when it reaches `rospack`. I am currently using the **Raspbian Jessie**, with the x11 desktop environment and trying to install the Desktop GUI version of ROS. I have followed every instruction till this point and am a bit baffled as to my next step.

[image: image description]

*Here's a picture of the terminal up until when the raspberry pi freezes*

Is there a way to change the command mentioned above so that I can ignore `rospack` completely and deal with the issue once the dependencies have been resolved (the objective of *Section 3.3* of the guide)?

It can also be observed that the Raspberry Pi hits 100% processing and the screen blacks out after a little bit. The clock skew warning comes up on every package. I am not sure if this has something to do with this crash.

**Please ask me if you would like to get a picture of higher defintion for the terminal up until the freeze and crash**

---

**UPDATE**

*Here is a picture of what happens after a little while when I try and move the mouse :*

[image: image description]

I'm going to try and run this on a different terminal altogether. The current terminal is a Yakuake (Guake).

---

**UPDATE 2**

As I suspected, it has nothing to do with the terminal I am using. I have found [this](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/master/rep-0128.rst) resource from [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/54181/how-to-exclude-one-package-from-the-catkin_make-build/) very question, to ignore the package `rospack`. I am going to try this out in a bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249515/raspberry-pi-crashes-when-i-try-to-build-the-catkin-workspace/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The freezes I encounter are usually either due to disk i/o (especially memory swapping) or hardware drivers. I guess the latter can be excluded, so you should monitor the memory exhaustion (e.g. use `watch -n 0.5 free -m`). You may try to disable swap (`sudo swapoff -a`), so the compilation is just killed when the physical memory is full.

Edit:

I am not sure whether catkin_make_isolated automatically parallelizes. If so, you might want to disable that (maybe append "-j1"?).

If it is the memory problem and disabling parallelization doesn't help, try to lower the complexity of the compilation of the problematic files.

- compile without -g flag (in CMake, set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Release)
- reduce optimization (this will make it slower) by explicitly using -Og or even -O0

Otherwise, getting more RAM is usually an option.

The above are just ideas from the top of my head. Make sure it is the memory swapping problem first. Also: Have you tried waiting?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-07**:
But I don't want the compilation killed, `rospack` is certainly very important and I would like to know how to actually build it in my catkin workspace.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-07**:
I'll try appending the `-j1` option and seeing what happens. Let me get back to you in a few minutes.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-07**:
`-j1` option seems to be working, but I am facing other errors. I guess, that's a topic for another question!

**Comment by [Haresh Karnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33873/haresh-karnan/) on 2018-02-26**:
-j1 did the trick. Thanks ! I have covered the setup as a writeup here :

https://hareshmiriyala.wordpress.com/2018/02/27/installing-robot-operating-system-on-a-raspberry-pi/

**Comment by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on 2019-08-13**:
-j1 did the trick